# The hermitian Einstein manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, kahler-einstein-metric

I take an hermitian manifold $(M,g,J)$ and I define from the riemannian curvature $R(X,Y)$ as a $2$-form:
$$
Ricc(J)= \sum_i R(J e_i,e_i)
$$
with $(e_i)$ an orthonormal basis of the tangent.
$$
2R(J)=J Ricc(J)+ Ricc(J)J
$$
$$
r(J)=tr(R(J))
$$
The hermitian Einstein metric verifies:
$$
R(J)_{ij}- \frac{1}{2} r(J)g_{ij}=0
$$
Have you references about such a metric?